# Why Visual Studio 2022 doesn't open a new browser tab or window when launching an asp.net app?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2022

I loaded [this project](https://github.com/dotnet/eShop) from Github and ran it. When I run the app, kestrel runs but the app doesn't come up in Chrome whether in a new tab or browser window. I have to do it manually. launchSettings.json has "launchBrowser": true set. I tried running in debug mode and without. Turned Enable Javascript on and off. Using VS 17.8. App is using .NET 8.

What needs to be done for VS to open the app in the browser? This is probably causing Hot Reload to not auto refresh the page when I make a change.

Answer (score 0):

With this [commit](https://github.com/dotnet/eShop/commit/68ab425f40dbd27d0c8f71e9af10dcd84876729c) the `README.md` was updated to have [Vs 2022 17.9](https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/vs/preview/) as a prerequisite.

Upgrade your Visual studio 2022 to 17.9.0.

> Prerequisites
>
> - (Windows only) Install Visual Studio. Visual Studio contains tooling     support for .NET Aspire that you will want to have.
>   **Visual Studio       2022 version 17.9 Preview**.
>
>   - During installation, ensure that the following are selected:
>
>     - ASP.NET and web development workload.
>     - .NET Aspire SDK component in Individual components.